# use a imageButton in GridView to select the row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to use a image button in a grid view to select a row so that i can then use the SelectedIndexChanged function to do other things. i have tried this:

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" CommandName="SelectRowGrid2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/select.png" />

  Protected Sub GridView2_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowCommand
        Select Case e.CommandName
            Case "SelectRowGrid2"
                'some code for selecting the index?
                Label1.Text = GridView2.SelectedIndex
        End Select
    End Sub
```

but it didn't even step in to the RowCommand sub when i went to debug it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You could set GridView's `AutoGenerateSelectButton` to true [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateselectbutton.aspx)
- You could set LinkButton's `CommandName` to "Select" [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx)

Or you could try following:

```
 Protected Sub ImgSelect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)  
     Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
     DirectCast(row.NamingContainer, GridView).SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex
 End Sub
```

aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
     <ItemTemplate >
         <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgSelect" OnClick="ImgSelect_Click" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: im using an image button not a linkbutton ive tried setting the command name to select and it doesn't do anything

Comment: that would be perfect if the image1 had a .click event or even existed in the vb side of the page :s

Comment: I don't know if you already have seen that i've added the aspx-part of the gridView where i've added the imagebutton to the TemplateField. Imagebutton has a Click-Event that you can handle(see my example). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.click.aspx

Comment: ive found the problem for some reason using a ajax ModalPopupExtender with the image button overrides any onclick event

Answer (score 1):

I have done this plenty times in c#.  Maybe I can help you out.

Some things I do different than you:

I call CellContentClick opposed to RowCommand.
 2. I think check to see, which cell in the row was clicked
 3. Check that the row is not null
 4. If it was my image button cell, get my row data

1.

```
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

2.

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == dgv.Columns["btnClmn"].Index)
```

3.

```
if (dgvAllApplication.CurrentRow != null)
```

4.

```
txtName.Text = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["App_Name"].Value.ToString();
```

Good Luck!

Comment: the grid view in vb.net doesn't have a cell content click handler :/

Comment: Ahh my mistake.  I was thinking DataGridView.  If you opt to use the datagridview, it will have a CellContentClick in VB I'm pretty sure.

@Houlahan thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

you can create on click event on the imagebutton and do whatever you need to do on that row from there

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)img.Parent.Parent;

        //do stuff
        //find label in the same row
        Label lbl = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");
    }
```

Comment: the image button doesn't have an on click event

Comment: Can you add an onclick event to it or you don't/can't use onclick event on the image button due to constraint or requirement?  I am just trying to understand what you are trying to do so I can provide a better solution.

Comment: handels Image1.Click 'handles clause requires a withEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.' for some reason the Image1 button image doesn't exist in the vb side of the aspx page :S ive added it to the grid view using the <ItemTemplate> im just tring to use a image to select the row instead of a link or a button